# ListView doesnt work when add ID

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio

so I uploaded screenshots

[image].

As you can see when I add 
android:id the array is changing and doesnt work check screenshoots.
Can you tell me why I can not add ID what Im doing wrong?

Comment: android:id="@+id/menu_glowne" you use id like this why and if u want more info than give more detail bcz its different problem than id if it not working than.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the prefix `@+`

```
android:id="@+id/menu_glowne"
```

Comment: Try to click that refresh icon beside the camera logo located above the Android Phone.

Comment: You mean same result and It didn't preview the Dummy values?

Comment: Yeah exacly, shouldnt I see my array list there? Like on my frist screenshoot?

Comment: can you post your XML menu_glowne array? Try also changing the 24 to 23 then click the refresh icon again beside the Globe logo. My guess is that this is a Bug in Android Studio XML preview.

Comment: Same I think it might be a problem in string-array.
'<resources>
<string-array name="menu_głowne">
<item>Napoje</item>
<item>Przekaski</item>
<item>Kafeteria</item>
</string-array>
</resources>'

Comment: Ah I get the issue it seems that you are using a different letter L `ł` this is not a regular English Character. I didn't notice it because it is not clear in the Image. If the problem still persist you can send the project in my email and I will fixed it.

Comment: Im so sorry that I wrote this like a retard, also ther problem wasn't in this ł cuz I did mistake in typping here on forum :P 
I decided to do screen when u can see the string.xml and activity also I changed to 23 like u can notice.
http://imgur.com/mMJ8yVr

Comment: I am wrong sorry for that, this is actually a normal behavior in ListView. I also tried adding some ID in my listview and yes the preview was gone. Therefore we cannot do anything about it :(.

Comment: So I shouldnt worry about this problem and can I go to next step in my project?

Comment: Yeah dont worry about it :)

Comment: I wrote on your e-mail. A question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already defined id you can use **@id** otherwise you'll have to use **@+id**.

Comment: Thank you for advice, but still doesnt work imgur.com/Ej7Vtc6

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 android:id="id/menu_glowne"
```

to

```
android:id="@+id/menu_glowne"
```

Sample code

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
</ListView>
```

And Check String.xml, is your array in this format?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>

  <string-array name="menu_glowne">
    <item>menue1</item>
    <item>menue2</item>
    <item>menue3</item>
  </string-array>

......................
....................
</resources>
```

Comment: Yeah there is no errors. But why after adding ID I see again default array like on second picture not like on the first one?

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
<Listview
..........
 android:id="@+id/menu_glowne"
/>
```

instead of

```
<Listview
..........
 android:id="id/menu_glowne"
/>
```

I hope it will help
And Check String.xml, is your array in this format?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>

  <string-array name="menu_glowne">
    <item>menue1</item>
    <item>menue2</item>
    <item>menue3</item>
  </string-array>

......................
....................
</resources>
```

Comment: is this in MainActivity.java?

Comment: Nope, its it in activity_main.xml, should I write something in MainActivity.java?
check my converstaion with Enzokie in this topic

Answer (score 0):

Just make change a little bit in your code: 
Add prefix @+ in this way

```
android:id="@+id/listView"
```

Comment: Hello Mayank Pandey still doesnt work imgur.com/Ej7Vtc6

Comment: You need to populate data in list with the help of adapter in this way. Then set adapter on list view. Code is given as:    String[] data= new String[]{"Napoje","Przekaski","Kafeteria"};    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);     ArrayAdapter<String> test = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);     lv.setAdapter(test);